# How to argue independence of random variables

Tags: random-variables, coupon-collector

I'm having trouble with a pretty basic idea- I just don't know how to argue that two events are independent. I know the definition: $$P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$$ but if we are given two events, like the roll of two different dice, how do we find $P(A\cap B)$? I know that when I was taught independence of events they would have me write out the probability chart, but in the case of things that aren't as small and easy to work with as dice, do we simply argue/assume things are independent and work from there?

It's very clear when two things aren't independent most of the time, but I'm having trouble thinking of how to prove things are independent. For instance, in the coupon collecting problem we say that the waiting time for each coupon are independent geometric random variables, how would we explicitly calculate $P(X_1 \cap X_2)$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the waiting times for the first and second coupon respectively?

Comment: Independent events mean that they 'act in a different dimension' in a sense. To illustrate, if you imagine the probability space as the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the usual area as probability, and imagine $A$ as a horizontal lane of width $P(A)$ and $B$ as a vertical lane of width $P(B)$, then the area of their intersection rectangle (i.e. $P(A\cap B)$) is just $P(A)\cdot P(B)$).

Comment: That helps with visualization, but I'm still not sure how to argue independence.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent formula for independence that is closer to how we reason is
$$P(A|B) = P(A|\bar{B}) = P(A).$$

With regards to random variables, saying that $X$ and $Y$ are independent amounts to saying that the distribution of $X$ given knowledge about $Y$ (i.e., given that $Y \in C$ for some Borel set $C$) is the same.

In the dice example, it is part of the physical understanding of the system that the roll of the first die has no impact on the result of the second one, thus, the distribution of the second roll must be invariant under any knowledge about the first.

The idea that the behaviour of the second roll is the same regardless of the first is not mathematical. Mathematics only explains the implications of such assumption on the stochastic model.

In the coupon collector's problem, we have a purely mathematical situation. Here we can make a precise argument, showing that the process of finding the third coupon is essentially the same regardless of whether the second one was found after 1, 2, 3 or $n$ attempts.

Comment: This makes use of conditioned probabilities, but of course if we have $P(A|B)$ then we have $P(A\cap B)$, assuming we know $P(B)$. It's not so much that I have issues understand, or translating probability, I just simply don't know how to make an argument for two things being independent.
How would you show that the probability is the same, for the coupon collector problem?

Comment: I think you'd just use the definition you stated in your question.  You run the coupon collector problem (either by analysis, or by actual experiment) a bunch of times, and collect statistics on how long you wait for the first coupon, and how long you wait for the second coupon, and record the numbers as ordered pairs.  If for every $x, y$, the probability of recording the pair $(x, y)$ is the probability of recording $(x, \cdot)$ times the probability of recording $(\cdot, y)$, the two variables are independent.  I can't tell if your difficulty is with using the definition, or its intuition.

Comment: @Anthony Do you agree that, after having found the second coupon out of $N$, the probability of finding a third one at each attempt is $(N-2)/N$? If you do, then you agree that the time taken to find the second one is irrelevant. Thus, the process of finding the $n$th ticket is independent of the time taken to find the other ones.

Comment: I agree with you but that's independent via English, not (explicitly) via the definition of independent.

Comment: @BrianTung The intuition makes sense to me, but as of now it seems like independence is something that needs to be assumed... Which I don't think it should be. I wouldn't want to run experiments, as that shouldn't be necessary, and also doesn't prove anything.

Comment: And @filipos, reading your revision confuses me a little more. You said the behavior of the dice is part of the stochastic model, but in intro probability courses don't they have students calculate the probabilities, and prove independence by explicitly showing, for instance, $P(1 \cap 2) = P(1)P(2)$. If we are assuming that the events are independent in the model, wouldn't this be a trivial result? (I mean, I suppose it is, but... I'm clearly missing something.)

Comment: @Anthony: The "experiments" are just conceptual.  You don't need to run them any more than you need to do so to determine any probability quantitatively.  I also don't see that independence needs to be assumed.  If you can determine P(A, B), P(A), and P(B), then you can assess independence directly.  If P(A, B) = P(A) P(B), they're independent; if they're unequal, they're not.

Comment: @Anthony Indeed, it is quite common in practice to use independence to derive probabilities instead of the other way around. It is the case with the coupon collector's problem, for example. To get an example of the opposite situation, imagine that you made a statistical study about the relation between gender and having a disease. Independence could be assessed by comparing the proportion of males and females with the given disease.