# Connection of independent, depended, mutually exclusive, and mutually events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

- Let say we made experiment that gave us N results.
- Let say m results are favorable for event A.
- Let say n results are favorable for event B.

Then we could picture it like that for independent, depended, mutually exclusive, and mutually events:
[events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvRCA.png)

According to the picture:

- independent and mutually exclusive events are the same thing
- dependent and mutually events are the same thing

**Questions:**

What the difference between:

1. independent and mutually exclusive events
2. depended and mutually events

Is it possible that event will be independent and mutually exclusive at the same time? If yes how we can use it?

Is it possible that event will be dependent and mutually at the same time? If yes how we can use it?

Comment: Where did you get the picture? The phrase "mutually events" is gramatically incorrect...

Comment: @5xum, I draw it according to mutually events description. So that it just how I understand it. Could you please point me where I am wrong?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1855104/what-is-the-intuition-behind-mathbbp-a-text-and-b-mathbbpa-ma/1855144#1855144

Comment: "mutually events" is non-sensical. Also, your image is incorrect. Can you write the definition?

Comment: @5xum, Event А is mutually from event B, if probability of А depends on if B happened or not

Comment: @NoNameYp Which textbook uses this phrase?

Comment: @5xum ISBN 978-5-406-00476-0 One of the best books about Probability theory. It's recommended for every one who is studying engineering-oriented professions.

Comment: I think I answered this question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279013/mutually-exclusive-events-with-non-zero-probability-are-always-dependent-is-t/3279054#3279054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two events $A,B$ are **[mutually exclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity)** iff: $$A\cap B=\varnothing\tag1$$

In words: it cannot happen that both events occur. At most one of them will occur, so the occurrence of $B$ **excludes** the occurrence of $A$ and vice versa. A consequence of this concerning probability is that: $$P(A\cap B)=P(\varnothing)=0$$

---

Two events $A,B$ are **[independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))** iff: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)\tag2$$

A consequence of this is: $$P(A\mid B)=P(A)=P(A\mid B^{\complement})$$

In words: the probability of  the occurrence of event $A$ is **not depending** on the occurrence (or non-occurence) of event $B$.

---

There is no mathematical concept "mutually events".

---

Two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive and independent at the same time iff :$$A\cap B=\varnothing\text{ and }0\in\{P(A),P(B)\}$$

In words: $A$ and $B$ have no outcome in common and at least one of them has probability $0$ to occur.

Comment: Yes. That case is handled in the last paragraph in my answer. An example: if $A=\varnothing$ then for any event $B$ it is true that the events $A$ and $B$ are independent and are also mutually exclusive.

Comment: If events can be independent and mutually exclusive  at the same time why we need both? Could we just use for example only mutually exclusive?

Comment: It seems that you are not well aware of the fact that "mutually exclusive" and "independent" are two concepts that are essentially different. In almost all cases they even exclude each other. The special case where two events $A,B$ are independent **and** mutually exclusive is a very very rare case. It can happen that an animal is green and is a carnivoor as well. Is that for you a reason to put aside one of the concepts "green" and "carnivoor"?

Comment: Accroding to definitions for independ and mutually exclusive events, we could say that (for both types of events): P(A + B) = P(A) + P(B). If I'm right than why we need both defenitions?

Comment: You are not right. If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$ because $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and consequently $P(A\cap B)=0$. But if $A$ and $B$ are are independent then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)\times P(B)$ because $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$. It seems that your mind is telling you over and over again that the concepts "mutually exclusive" and "independent" are the same. Do not listen to that anymore. The concepts are distinct, as becomes as clear as crystal if you read carefully my answer.

Comment: thank you for your explanation! 
Let's imagine the following: we throw two dices at the same time:
- Event A is to get 3 at the first dice
- Event B is to get 5 at the second dice

This events are independent. This two events are also not mutually exclusive, because if we got any number at the first dice it is not exclude that we will get 5 at the second one.
Consequently, this two events are mutually.
So it means that mutually events exists.
Please, correct me if I wrong, cause I completly lost.

Comment: I have heard of events that are "mutually exclusive" and of events that are "not mutually exclusive". It seems that you want to create a new label for events that are not mutually exclusive. You call the events "mutually". But that label is not practicized in probability theory (and also there is no need for it). Just keep calling the events "not mutually exclusive". The example you gave is a nice example of independent and not mutually exclusive events. Nothing more (don't call them mutually) and nothing less. Btw, mutually stands for "each other".